# Azure Python SDK automation runbook - error - 'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-authentication, azure-identity, azure-python-sdk

I found few posts related to Azure Python error message - `'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'`, but I am testing my code from Azure portal, I am using Automation Account runbook. I prepared script for changing TLS property on Storage Account. I have two az subscriptions located in different tenants (subA - service provider, subB - service customer), I am using Azure Lighthouse to provide admin access from subA account to subB. I am using SPN registered in subA Azure AD. I tested Python code on my laptop and all works as expected, I was able to modify Storage Account located in subB using subA SPN - Service Principal. I am testing the same code from Azure Portal - Automation Account runbook and I am facing an error `self._creds.signed_session(session)AttributeError: 'ClientSecretCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'`. In Automation Account I have imported packages, list below.

[image]

My Python code, works as expected from my Laptop, throwing mentioned error when executing as an automation runbook from Azure Portal.

```
import sys
import json
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import azure.mgmt.storage

subscription_id = "subB-subscriptionID"
tenant_id = "subA-TenantID"
client_id = "subA-clientID"
client_secret = "subA-clientSecret"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret)

storage_client = azure.mgmt.storage.StorageManagementClient(
    credentials=credential,
    subscription_id=subscription_id
)

storage_account = storage_client.storage_accounts.update(
    "ResourceGroupName",
    "StorageAccountName",
    {
        "properties": {
            "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2"   
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Automation runbooks I decided to use Function app. Function contains all Python code and all works fine, I tested the solution and all works as expected.